# Creating .invoke() from scratch. Why does function work but method returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, underscore.js

I'm doing precourse work for a JavaScript-based programming school and I've run into a problem. The 
assignment is to rewrite some underscore.js methods from scratch so we know how they work, rather than just relying on them blindly. **My `_.invoke` will pass functions refs but not method names.**

Here's the original problem:

```
// Calls the method named by functionOrKey on each value in the list.
// Note: you will nead to learn a bit about .apply to complete this.

_.invoke = function(collection, functionOrKey, args) {
};
```

My solution so far using `_.map()` I wrote previously (which passed its own tests):

`_.invoke = function(collection, functionOrKey, args) {
    return _.map(collection, function(value) {
      return functionOrKey.apply(value, args);
    });
  };`

My solution **will** support passing a function for `functionOrKey`. For example (from the Mocha Test Suite):

```
var reverse = function(){
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};

var reversedStrings = _.invoke(['dog', 'cat'], reverse);

reseversedStrings = "['god', tac']; //YAY!!
```

However, when it comes to passing a method, such as toUpperCase, I get the error message: "TypeError: undefined is not a function". Any suggestions appreciated!

**EDIT:** Found the failing test:

```
var upperCasedStrings = _.invoke(['dog', 'cat'], 'toUpperCase');

expect(upperCasedStrings).to.eql(['DOG', 'CAT']);
```

Comment: You didn't post the example that fails... How do you call it with `toUpperCase`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't allow me to post the exact example that fails, because I haven't solved it. I know that the method it's testing is `toUpperCase` because to start with I ran `_.invoke` just `return functionOrKey` to see what mocha was passing for the method.

Comment: What, like `_.invoke(['dog', 'cat'], 'toUpperCase')`?

Comment: @minitech Yes, I think that's the gist of it. It passes the TypeError above when mocha tries to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when it comes to passing a method, such as toUpperCase, I get the error message: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Well, you're not passing a "method". See @elclarns' answer for how to pass a bound function.

What you are passing is a property name, which is a string - and when `functionOrKey` is the string `'toUpperCase'` it does not have an [`apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). You will need to check the [type of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) that parameter, and act accordingly. When it's a string, you will want to use

```
return value[key].apply(value, args);
```

in the `map` callback.

Btw, your `args` parameter shouldn't be an array, but should be built from the dynamic [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments). If you want to "cheat" (or see the full solution), have a look at the [annotated source code of Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-25).

Comment: Trying not to cheat. :-). Implemented your solution and it works! Thanks for the tip. Could use additional clarification, however, on the args parameter. The source code shows args as an array, created using slice method.

Comment: Yes, exactly, an array created from all the `arguments` that follow the `collection` and `functionOrKey` parameters. In your code, it's just an array that is passed as the third parameter. `invoke([1,16,255], "toString", 16)` instead of `invoke([…], "toString", [16])`

Answer (score 2):

```
My solution would be:
_.invoke = function(collection, functionOrKey, args) {
//invoke when provided a method name
        if(typeof functionOrKey === 'string'){
          return _.map(collection, function(val){
            return val[functionOrKey](args);
          });
        }
//invoke when provided a function reference
        return _.map(collection, function(val){
          return functionOrKey.apply(val, args);
        });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, but maybe it can be simpler. If you want to call a method and invoke it for each item in the array, you could simply use the builtin `map` like this:

```
var invoke = Function.bind.bind(Function.call)

var reverse = function() {
  return this.split('').reverse().join('')
}

var result = ['dog', 'cat'].map(invoke(reverse)) //=> ['god', 'tac']
```

You can also use it with builtin methods:

```
['dog', 'cat'].map(invoke(''.toUpperCase)) //=> ['DOG', 'CAT']
```

I think this solves your particular issue, but `invoke` doesn't forward any additional arguments to the function it calls, as per Underscore documentation. In that case you can try to use what you've got so far plus the above helper, and capture any additional arguments.

Comment: Maybe to make my issue more clear: I have not built-in methods...my assignment is to write, from scratch, all the methods in the underscore.js library.

Comment: `apply` is builtin method, and `split` and `reverse` and `join`, not sure what you mean... `map` is as builtin as those. Underscore has some duplicate methods to cover very old browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately, I can't choose my own declared function to pass, mocha is testing with its own.

That taken into consideration, I've implemented your suggestion like this:

`_.invoke = function(collection, functionOrKey, args) {
  var invoke = Function.bind.bind(Function.call);
  var result = collection.map(invoke(functionOrKey));
  return result; };`

It will still work if a function is passed, like your reverse, but when mocha tries to pass the method, it displays the same error. :-(